My Icon from VS Code is a gear instead of the usual logo
My VS Code icon is a gear instead of the usual logo from the program.
It happened while I was trying to add "open in code" context to right click in folders.
I tried some solutions to add this feature, but none did the trick. One of them made the correct icon of VS Code change into a gear, and unfortunately, I don't remember exactly what I did to make that happen.
After that, I searched for solutions about the icon, and most of them envolved editing the code.desktop in /usr/share/applications. I changed the lines
"Icon=vscode" to  "Icon = new_path_to_vscode_icon.png", but nothing happened.
I uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code, but the icon remained the same.
I asked ChatGPT for help, and tried clearing icon cache for all themes with:
sudo rm -r /usr/share/icons/*/icon-theme.cache

but it stayed the same.
What can I do to restore the original icon from VS Code?
I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
Image showing the gear icon in favorites bar and search menu

I found the solution on this question Wrong/corrupted icon in dash.
I deleted the code.desktop file that was in ~/.local/share/applications, and now my VS Code icon is restored.

Remove completely and install from their official website.
Download the .deb file from the website.
Go to the installed directory, usually "Downloads" in the terminal.
Type :

sudo dpkg -i "name_of_the_package"

where name_of_the package is the file you downloaded now.
It will do the necessary thing. The shortcuts will be placed in your applications list.

I tried that now, but unfortunately, the wrong icon persisted.
